# redirect pages from Umbraco site to external web pages

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I have a Umbraco website.

I want to use the same Umbraco site and need to redirect about 10 pages to a external pages including the home page.

I think we have Umbraco 6.2

Please, can you tell me how to do this?

I do not know if it is a code change or a settings change.

I appreciate if you can advise.

Thank you!

Comment: How come that I get a direct search hit *in the official documentation of Umbraco* when I search for "redirect pages from Umbraco site to external web pages" (your own question title) and it did not occur to you to try that before asking?

Comment: Telling people to stay away from your questions is not a good start on Stack Overflow, don't do that. Downvotes are the expected and normal thing for questions that don't meet the minimum standards here. And one of the minimum standards is that you mention documentation you've read, that you show your code (!) and that you explain the errors or issues you have encountered.

Comment: If somebody can tell me this need code changes or if we can do this with the configurations then I can do that. Posting all the ways which I was tried will be not helped.
Umbraco 6.2
I am getting a notification to upgrade it to the next subverison. So this is why I mention 6.2
I am new to Umbraco. I used other CMS before. But not Umbraco.

Comment: @Yma; @Tomalak is actually trying to help you as otherwise you won't get any proper help.

Here are some tips before asking a (good) question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Also for your case, first check the previous answers by doing some research. You don't even know your Umbraco version, which could be crucial as things could be completely different from one version to another. So use the existing documentation online to find out your Umbraco version, too.

Comment: I told you it is 6.2

Comment: Umbraco v6.2.4 (Assembly version: 1.0.5394.15649)

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco 6.2 is a very old version and If you have the chance to remake the site in a newer version I would strongly recommend this as it is far out of support range. Current documentation doesn't even go back that far (7 -> 9)

That being said, the quickest way to not touch the code base at all and "just" make the redirects work. Is the use the fact that Umbraco sites rely heavily on IIS hosting. You can edit the web.config file and tell IIS that when a certain url is hit, to return a redirect.

Here is some Official documentation from microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module